# Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' when selecting columns from a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame. When selecting these columns, i get a "Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'" error.

The dataframe prints this;

```
DataFrame[ticket_id: bigint, subject: string, priority: string, priority_id: bigint]
```

However, when I use the same query I use at other parts of the code (which work),

```
groups = subject_tickets.select(subject_tickets.ticket_id, subject_tickets.subject).toPandas()
```

I get hit with the "Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'", but it works with the others that contain different variables.

The expected result is to call the "ticket_id" and "subject" column from the dataframe.

Comment: Try this, `select($"ticket_id", $"subject").toPandas()`

Comment: I tried, it did not work.